# copying columns from worksheet to masterworksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have following problem. I recorded a macro which copies a worksheet called "copiedworksheet" and pastes it to my masterworkbook called "masterworkbook", which has my mastersheet called "mastersheet". Now both "copiedworksheet" and "mastersheet" are in the same workbook and i want to copy columns A;B;C;D from "copiedworksheet" and paste it to columns B;D;E;G in "mastersheet" in row. (A to B, B to D etc).

Can anyone help me by this?

Comment: Have you tried recording what you want to do; then looking at the code generated by Excel?  You need to show that you have at least attempted to solve the problem yourself before anyone will help you here

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyPst()
    Sheets("copiedworksheet").Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=Sheets("mastersheet").Range("B:B")
    Sheets("copiedworksheet").Range("B:B").Copy Destination:=Sheets("mastersheet").Range("D:D")
    Sheets("copiedworksheet").Range("C:C").Copy Destination:=Sheets("mastersheet").Range("E:E")
    Sheets("copiedworksheet").Range("D:D").Copy Destination:=Sheets("mastersheet").Range("G:G")
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i have one more question, i would like to paste these columns in to the next empty row at "mastersheet". How can i do this?

Comment: you mean to copy data from column to ROW? Please give example